# Drawing large no of rectangles in tkinter?

Tags: python, performance, tkinter, rectangles

Have been trying to draw a large no rectangles in tkinter python. Using for loop to achieve that seems to slow. Is there a way of doing it more efficiently and speedily within less than 3secs.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=500)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)

Vscroll = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
Hscroll = Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)

for cols in range(50):
    for ros in range(7000):
        x1 = cols * 135
        y1 = ros * 30
        x2 = x1 + 135
        y2 = y1 + 30

        canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,width=1,fill="white",outline="grey60")

canvas.update_idletasks()
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), xscrollcommand=Hscroll.set)
canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"), yscrollcommand=Vscroll.set)
Hscroll.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky='ew')
Vscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='ns')

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    mainloop()
```

Your help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Well, you are creating 350,000 rectangles; this is going to be slow. What are you trying to achieve? If you want to have a large scrollable spreadsheet, you should probably think about only drawing visible elements.

Comment: Tkinter is not a high-performance GUI library, so don't expect too much.

Comment: Prepare your own canvas in form of numpy array, write all those rectangles to it yourself, send to Tkinter canvas only the final result. First part (writing all those rectangles to numpy array) may be optimized in numba for speed

Comment: @danielkullmann Thanks for this reply! I also thought about this but what borders me is that, if only visible rows are to be drawn, how will the scrollbar be updated that it contains more rows beneath?

Comment: It merely take 5 seconds to pop-up window. That why you had range of rows 7000. You can't get less than 3 seconds.

Comment: @dankal444 Thank for the reply! The statement "send to tkinter canvas the final result". Please clarify on that

Comment: @ApataJohn Something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564720/using-tkinter-to-display-images-from-a-numpy-array).